# Getting the MAC address by arp -a

Tags: powershell

```
$MAC = arp -a $address | Select-String ('([0-9a-f]{2}-){5}[0-9a-f]{2}')
```

I am not getting the MAC address filtered. It's showing me complete output.

Comment: which mac address do you want to get?

Comment: `... | Select-Object -Expand Matches | Select-Object -Expand Value`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: $address, has a local ip address of my clients, i wanted to get their mac addresses

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ty it worked

Answer (score 1):

As Ansgar already pointed out, you'll want the `Value` property value from the resulting `Match` objects:

```
$MAC = arp -a $address | Select-String '([0-9a-f]{2}-){5}[0-9a-f]{2}' | Select-Object -Expand Matches | Select-Object -Expand Value
```

or, using property enumeration:

```
$MAC = (arp -a $address | Select-String '([0-9a-f]{2}-){5}[0-9a-f]{2}').Matches.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use template

```
$template=@" 
{row*:  {IP:0\.0\.0\.0}           {Mac:54-64-d9-6d-28-a3}     {TypeAdress:dynamique}} 
{row*:  {IP:255\.255\.255\.255}         {Mac:ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff}     {TypeAdress:statique}}  
"@

#you can then filter directly
arp -a '192.168.0.1'  | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | select {$_.Row.Mac}

# or you can filter after
arp -a  | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | where {$_.Row.IP -eq '192.168.0.1'} | select {$_.Row.Mac}

#you can too get list of object like this
arp -a  | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template |  %{[pscustomobject]@{IP=$_.Row.IP;MAC=$_.Row.Mac;Type=$_.Row.TypeAdress}}
```